# Свои сессии на MySQL

Tags: php, сессия, mysql

Хочу написать свои сессии, которые будут храниться в sql.

Создал таблицу **sessions** с 4-мя полями: id, key, value, time.

```
$session->add('ключ сессии', 'значение сессии'); // создаём сессию
$session->get('ключ сессии'); // получаем значение сессии
$session->delete('ключ сессии'); // удаляем сессию
```

Вроде бы всё хорошо. Но как привязывать сессию к пользователю? По IP глупо, так как могут два компьютера с одинаковыми IP быть одновременно на сайте и тогда неизвестно что получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для пользователя выполнившего вход(авторизацию) у меня сделано вот так :
в базу, в таблицу users_sessions пишем :

**session** - 128-значный ключ сессии(любые 3 позиции из данных пользователя + текущее время в мили.сек. оборачиваем в md5)

**users_id** - уникальный id пользователя, который пользуется этой сессией

**date_updated** - время последнего обновления(если хотим чтобы сессия были короткими)

с каждым заходом пользователя на сайт мы делаем проверку на существование сессии в базе(128-значный ключ отдаём пользователю в печеньки(cookies) когда тот выполнил вход)

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, а как Вы потом по вашему ключу ищите? Там же время, получается Вы записываете этот ключ в куки или что?

Comment: Ключ и session тоже самое, при входе генерируется session и записывается в базу вместе с остальными данными(как и описал в ответе) а также session отдаётся пользователю в куки.

Answer (score 0):

Выдавать пользователю GUID и хранить его в куках, например...

Comment: @SoWa, что за GUID?

Comment: Ну так и кирпич на голову - чтож теперь, из дома не выходить? :)

Answer (score 0):

Может брать существующую сессию и просто хранить ее в бд с привязкой дополнительной инфы. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: <offtop>А просто, ради идеи? Ну напало на человека желание)</offtop>